# getRouteByKeyName another model laravel

Tags: php, laravel

### I have two models:

- Categories
- CategoriesTranslations

In model categories I writed:

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){
    return 'alias';
}
```

Column alias belogns model CategoriesTranslations. 
How I can return alias from model CategoriesTranslations? 
My code is not working.

I tryed:

Add getRouteKeyName on CategoriesTranslations:

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){
    return 'alias';
}
```

And in Categories add:

```
public function categoryTranslations() {
    return $this->hasOne(CategoriesTranslations::class);
}

public function getRouteKeyName() {
    return $this->categoryTranslations->getRouteKeyName();
}
```

I get error `Call to a member function getRouteKeyName() on null` When want show category by getRouteKeyName. How fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You must use relationships between Categories and CategoriesTranslations.

In your Categories model:

```
public function categoriesTranslations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CategoriesTranslations::class);
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    $this->categoryTranslations->where('locale', Auth::user()->locale)->first()->getRouteKeyName();
}
```

Now you can call `getRouteKeyName()` from any instance of the Categories model and it will pull it from the CategoriesTranslations table.

** The potential fix here was adding in the `where()` statement and the `first()` method. Change the `Auth::user()->locale` to wherever you are storing which locale to use.

Comment: I need return 'alias' from model CategoriesTranslations in model Categories. How I can do it?  ``return $category->categoryTranslations->getRouteKeyName(); `` ?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about the relationship between the two models? Are there multiple CategoriesTranslations for each Category?

Comment: Yes. In CategoriesTranslations I have dates for multiple categories.

Comment: @Tatata, I've updated my answer a bit. See if that works for you. We still need to define the proper relationship here though. This will work if it's one-to-one. If it's one-to-many, that will change things quite a bit!

Comment: So are you wanting the route key name for the FIRST related CategoriesTranslations? Picture this: if we called `$category->categoryTranslations` we may get 3 returned CategoriesTranslations instances. Which one would you want to get the route key name from? The first?

Comment: Call to a member function getRouteKeyName() on null. I get this error.

Comment: @Tatata, can you answer the question from above?

Comment: @Tatata,  you may have updated the question, but you never answered MY QUESTION in the comments about which relationship to use. If multiple CategoriesTranslations are found, which one do you want to use to find the route key name? You can't use all of them. You have to pick one. Also, you can't use the hasOne method anymore if you want a one-to-many relationship. Use the Laravel docs to learn how to set up relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable i use this package. Please see structure of models.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. We are here to HELP, not to do the work for you.

Comment: I have in categories_translations multiple categories. key: categories_id belongs to table categories.id. See please structure of categories_translations table: https://imgur.com/a/swNhf I tryied use hasMany, belongsTo. Not working. I get always: Method getRouteKeyName does not exist. I need set `alias` column to categories model.

Comment: I think I know the issue now. See my revised answer.

Comment: `Call to a member function getRouteKeyName() on null`

Comment: Forget the `getRouteKeyName()` method for now! It's not helping! Focus on the relationship, and get that working first. That is the reason that you are getting the null error. Try using `dd($category->categoriesTranslations);` or the 'die and dump' method.

Comment: I want to inject Page model into the controller via route. Page model uses PageSlug model which has to be checked on it's slug and locale column. (2 variables in the route look like: {lang}/pages/{slug} )Does anyone know if that's possible? @GoogleMac